# How to configure Maven project such that dependencies have to be provided after deployment?

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I want to try out a few things with Spark but the problem is that our cluster does provide e.g. Spark 1.6.0 dependencies already locally but on the other hand I need to provide those dependencies on my local development machine in my maven repository.

This would be my current pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>masterthesis.code</groupId>
    <artifactId>wordvectors</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <stanford-corenlp.version>3.6.0</stanford-corenlp.version>
        <sista.version>3.3</sista.version>
        <gson.version>2.6.2</gson.version>
        <spark.version>1.6.0</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Apache Spark -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Stanford CoreNLP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>${stanford-corenlp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>${stanford-corenlp.version}</version>
            <classifier>models-english</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SISTA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.arizona.sista</groupId>
            <artifactId>processors</artifactId>
            <version>${sista.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- GSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But how can I configure this such that the final deployed .jar does *not* include e.g. `spark-core_2.10` but instead load that dependency from the cluster?

Comment: if the answer provided solves your problems, please accept it so we can close this question !

Comment: @eliasah I ended up using the shade plugin for Maven actually. I'll post my solution asap but I'm currently working on another project.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to configure your dependency inside the provided scope e.g :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The provide scope is much like `compile` (scope by default), but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Comment: You're the second guy with that solution ^^ This does not work because I'd have to provide the jar and all it's dependencies on my dev-machine as well at runtime which is not what I want.

Comment: Please explain what you want then ! This is what I understood from your question. ;)

Comment: "*how can I configure this such that the final deployed .jar does not include e.g. spark-core_2.10 but instead load that dependency from the cluster?*" is actually what I need. My local machine should provide everything from the local repository but when I deploy to the cluster I want certain dependencies to be removed/excluded from that final jar file.

Comment: If the jars are available on the cluster, this is a way of doing it, or you can force the jars location (other solution).

Comment: If I set  `provided` then running my project on the local machine throws `NoClassDefFoundError` for all classes in dependencies I don't provide explicitly. That means that I have to click together the main dependency and all it's sub-dependencies until all those exceptions are gone. This is surely not an optimal solution ^^

Comment: can you try with `system` please instead ? If this doesn't work. You'll to define a profile so you can differentiate between local and cluster mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108163/discussion-between-eliasah-and-displayname).